# Powerapp formula not returning desired value

Tags: powerapp

All,
Formulas below not returning desired value.

If(Dropdown2_2.Selected.Project,Average(UKI_DIS_QUA_Compliance,Quality_score))

Or

If(Title =Dropdown2_2.Selected.Project,Average(UKI_DIS_QUA_Compliance,Quality_score))

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your requirements in detail? based on that we can suggest you the right formula.

Comment: if title equals to project on dropdown, I would like to calculate QUA average score

Comment: Where are you adding above formula? On label control or in variable or somewhere else?

Comment: If a project is selected (tittle). I'd like the average of a column on a Sharepoin list (quality score).

Comment: @GaneshSanap, is this syntax correct? Average(UKI_DIS_QUA_Compliance, Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value)

Comment: No. Syntax of average function is: `Average( Table, NumericalFormula )`. So, for 2nd parameter, you have to provide the name of number column in `UKI_DIS_QUA_Compliance` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of **Dropdown2_2.Selected.Project**, most probably will be an object instead of a text.

Expand the object and get the text value the condition will work.

hope this will solve your problem, if so please mark this as the answer.

Thank you...